# Creating JMS/MQ templates and listeners for multiple hosts

Tags: java, spring-boot, jms, ibm-mq, spring-jms

I have a Java Spring/Boot application that connects to multiple MQ hosts. I am using JmsTemplate to send the messages, and I am trying to configure JmsListeners to receive the messages. I am having 2 different issues.

For sending the message, I would like to give the JmsTemplate the list of hosts, and have it use the standard failover - use the first, if it's down, switch to the second, etc. The issue I have with this is that once the failover happens, there doesn't seem to be an attempt to revert back to the first host in the list. How can I make the application check to see if the first host is back online?

For receiving the message, I want to create a listener for each unique host / return queue combination, and have all the listeners active at once. The number of hosts and queue names is variable. I can probably get by with a single queue, but I need the multiple hosts (I've seen solutions for 2 hosts, but I need "n"). I am able to create and register the listeners using JmsListenerEndpointRegistrar. The issue is that it seems that behind the scenes, the listeners are using the JmsTemplate that I use for sending messages, and it is using the failover behavior - only the listener associated with the first host is active until that host goes down, then the listener associated with the second host becomes active, etc. How can I make all listeners active all at once? I think I could do this if I could tie a listener to a specific JmsTemplate, but I don't see how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, your best bet would be to have a CCDT and set `ibm.mq.ccdtUrl` in `application.properties` to point at the CCDT.

See the GitHub repo home for the mq-jms-spring-boot-starter for a list of all the configuration attributes -  https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-jms-spring

By using a CCDT, you are letting the underlying MQ Java Client code perform the failover.